# cmbState_SelectedValueChanged event is not getting triggered second time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two combobox state and city ,when I select value in state First time value changes in `city combobx` as per `stateselection` But second time if I select another state than City values doesn't changes according to state value ,Why event is not getting triggered second time ? I tried `selectedIndexchanged event` also but same issue with this also , or Which event should I use than ,below is code I am using

```
private void cmbState_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stateName = cmbState.SelectedItem.ToString();
            DataTable dt3 = DBHandling.GetcityDataTable(stateName);
            if (dt3 != null && dt3.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
                {
                    cmbCity.Items.Add(dr["CityName"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how did you know it's not triggered second time? have you tried debugging?

Comment: Please revise the provided sample code. According to it, whenever you select another state, the cities of that state will be **added** to cmbCity. If you have clicked/selected on three states, cmbCity will contain the cities of all three states. (I assume here that your code is not hindered from running by another code bug.)

Comment: @KingKing Yes Now I checked again for different values while debugging,but for some value of state `city` is changing and for some value its not ,I am not understanding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting triggered..

You are not clearing the list and hence you were not able to see the new values you added

```
cmbCity.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the event is not firing the second time?  It looks like you might need to clear your city combo box before adding the cities to it when the state selection changes.  Right now, you are only adding cities to the list. When you change state selection a second time, the list of cities is still there, and you are just adding more cities to the list.

Try this:

```
    private void cmbState_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string stateName = cmbState.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DataTable dt3 = DBHandling.GetcityDataTable(stateName);

        cmbCity.Items.Clear();

        if (dt3 != null && dt3.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
            {
                cmbCity.Items.Add(dr["CityName"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please fix the code indentation of the method signature. Otherwise, your answer is fine :)